# Ways to order people in distinct rooms

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

How many ways can you order $4$ people into two distinct rooms?

The only way I can think of handling this problem is listing out every combination, which got me $16$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it this way, you arrange all of the people in a line, directing each person in the line either to the left or to the right room. For every person there are $2$ possibilities for the room which they may be directed to, the same for the next and the one after that. So for one person there are $2$ possibilities, and for the second there are $2\cdot 2$ possibilities, i.e. all of the previous combinations are doubled as with every new person in the line there are $2$ ways that they may be ordered into the rooms.

This generalities to $2^n$ possibilities for a line with $n$ people.

To elaborate imagine all of the different combinations of left and right you could acheive i.e. $\{l,r,r,...,l,l\},...,\{r,r,l,...,r,l\}$. Now should another person be added to this line, you can "tack on" an $l$ or an $r$ to all of your previous combinations giving you twice as many as before.

Comment: Very intuitive explanation. If there were three distinct rooms, then there would be $3^n$ possibilities, and $k$ rooms would be $k^n$ possibilities. Thank you!

Comment: That generalization is indeed correct, glad I could be of help!